# My UIButton doesn't call the method targeted

Tags: swift, uibutton, selector

I honestly don't know what is wrong with that #selector :

```
func iterate() {
    scrollView.subviews[0].subviews[0].addSubview(arrowButton)
    arrowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: arrowButton)
}

func pressButton() {
    print("pouet pouet pouet")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    iterate()
}
```

(Don't mind the layout thing, I've removed all the constraints for clarity's sake)

When I press my button, nothing is printed.

I'm getting crazy with that #selector, how such an important piece of development is still using this ObjC crap ?

edit : my UIBUtton is on top of all the layer, or at least that's what XCode debugging tool is saying (the button is in the right bottom corner) =
[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Try just `pressButton` without the `self.`?

Comment: I've tried, I've tried with like every syntax I could find online, but nothing worked… I'm losing at least half a day every time I have to use #selector, seriously…

Comment: Actually, the problem might not be the selector. It might be somewhere else altogether. Check if `viewDIdLoad` is called at all.

Comment: Since my Button and everything in the viewDidLoad is showing up, I'm thinking my viewDidLoad is called, nope ? I put a print() in it and it's also showing up.

Comment: Okay. I suggest that you create a new project in Xcode and try to reproduce this problem with the shortest code possible. Then post it here. Also include other steps you did.

Comment: So, did you solve this? Have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think error in this line
    (scrollView.subviews[0].subviews[0].addSubview(arrowButton))

may be your button added under at View  jsut check

```
func iterate() {
    scrollView.subviews[0].subviews[0].addSubview(arrowButton)
    arrowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressButton), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func pressButton() {
    print("pouet pouet pouet")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    iterate()
}
```

Comment: I've suspected that, but I've added  self.view.bringSubview(toFront: arrowButton), and I've checked with XCode debugging tool (see edits) and it's definitely on top…

Comment: Are you add arrowButton Frame , Are you using constraints , just set frame for UIbutton

Comment: I'm using constraints, but then again, the button position in Z, Y or X, the height or the width is definitely okay, xcode doesn't complain about anything with the layout, and everything is okay in the simulator. Just this M********ing #selector…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be because of some issue with the syntax. Try this...

```
arrowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And for the touch action...

```
func pressButton(_ sender : UIButton){

 print("Button Tapped")
 }
```

Comment: Hmm...try adding this ....arrowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Just to debug the issue is not because of the `view hierarchy`, try replacing this line of your code:

```
scrollView.subviews[0].subviews[0].addSubview(arrowButton)
```

with

```
self.view.addSubview(arrowButton)
```

**2.** Check the following properties of your `arrowButton` are not set to `false` somewhere in your code:

```
isEnabled, isUserInteractionEnabled
```

These 2 properties must be `true` in order for the `arrowButton` to receive `touch events`.

**3.** Check if any other view is not added on the top of your `arrowButton`.

**4.** There is no issue with the `selector` you provided. It is working perfectly fine. I used the below code and it works for me:

```
func iterate()
{
    let arrowButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    arrowButton.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(arrowButton)
    arrowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: arrowButton)
}
```

I think the `view hierarchy` is somehow causing the issue.